# Guice: Why must @Singleton-annotated classes be immutable/thread safe?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, junit, scope, guice

*NOTE:  This question is **not** about Singleton classes as described in Gamma94 (ensuring only one object ever gets instantiated.)*

I read the [Guice documentation](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-guice&s=google-guice&t=Scopes) about the @Singleton attribute:

```
Classes annotated @Singleton and @SessionScoped must be threadsafe.
```

Is this the case even if I don't intend to access the object from more than one thread?  If so, why?

Comment: "threadsafe" means that an object will behave as expected, even if accessed concurrently by 2 or more threads. Now if you are 100% sure that your object will be accessed by exactly one thread (eg because your whole application is mono-thread), then it is automatically threadsafe in the context of your application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If an object is only ever accessed from a single thread, it doesn't need to be threadsafe even it's a Guice `@Singleton`. Guice doesn't do any multithreading internally that could cause a non-threadsafe singleton to break... the process of building the `Injector` is all done on the thread that calls `Guice.createInjector` and any dynamic provisioning is done on the thread that calls `provider.get()`. Of course, a singleton is only going to be created once and then just returned each time it's needed... when it's created depends on whether it's bound as an *eager* singleton (always created at startup) and whether the `Injector` is created in `Stage.DEVELOPMENT` (created only if and when needed) or `Stage.PRODUCTION` (created at startup).

It's very often the case that singletons can be accessed from multiple threads at the same time though (particularly in web applications), hence the warning. While many developers will understand that a singleton needs to be threadsafe in that case, others may not and I imagine it was considered worth it to warn them.

Comment: Thanks Colin.  It would have saved me a lot of confusion if they left that seemingly obvious general programming advice out of the documentation (to make sure classes that are to be accessed by multiple threads are designed to do so.)

Comment: @glenviewjeff: Making Singletons thread-safe is sound advice.  If the documentation says that Singletons must be thread-safe within the context of Guice, then you better make them thread safe.  Otherwise, you are essentially breaking their contract, and they can make no assurances that your code will behave as expected.  It's easy to make Singletons thread safe, so you might as well do it.

Comment: @Robert, that's what I was thinking, that if Guice says so, I better listen to the advice until I get a more definitive answer and explanation.  The problem is that making the Singleton thread safe is not as easy as you might think because I'm invoking a (somewhat obscure) ORM and I'm not sure about the thread safety of the methods.

Comment: @glenviewjeff: This has nothing to do with the Singleton (static instance) design pattern. Guice doesn't do any multithreading internally that could cause a non-threadsafe singleton to break... the process of building the `Injector` is all done on the thread that calls `Guice.createInjector` and any dynamic provisioning is done on the thread that calls `provider.get()`.

Comment: @ColinD, thanks for the explanation.  Maybe you could add this information to your answer?

Comment: Is there any official documentation on Guice injector not doing any multithreading internally?